ASP.NET Core DI framework - how to resolve a class depending on the caller class
We are migrating an old .Net framework application to Net 8. We have our own ILogger interface and our own Logger implementation and we are using the custom ILogger in thousand of classes. Now we want to "replace" it with Microsoft.ILogger<T> and take the advantage of using the default .NET DI container.
The first step we did is to create a wrapper around Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger.
public class NewLoggerWrapper<T> : Custom.ILogger
{
    private readonly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger _logger;
    
    public NewLoggerWrapper(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<T> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    
    // Implements all Custom.ILogger methods that calling the
    // corresponding Microsoft.ILogger methods
}

Now the point is how to register the Custom.ILogger in the service collection so it points to a generic NewLoggerWrapper<T>. For ex.:
public class Repository
{
    public Repository(Custom.ILogger logger)
    {
    }
}

When Repository->Custom.ILogger is resolved, we want NewLoggerWrapper<Repository> to be called. We can instantiate NewLoggerWrapper with a predefined class, like NewLoggerWrapper<Application>, but have no idea how to instantiate NewLoggerWrapper<SpecificGeneric> for a SpecificGenericGeneric class.

I suggest you could try this builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(Custom.ILogger), typeof(NewLoggerWrapper<>));.

I get this exception when I try this approach.
Cannot instantiate implementation type 'NewLoggerWrapper[T]' for service type 'Custom.ILogger'.

I'm very sorry to break it to you, but the solution you're looking for is non-existing in MS.DI. It's simply impossible to achieve this due to the limitations in the library. There is a kind-of workaround where you go through all registration and replace them based on the existing of your Custom.ILogger dependency, but that only works part of the time. If you require this behavior, I suggest moving to DI Container that has (built-in) support for this.

To elaborate on my comment MS.DI does not support context-based injections, like some other DI Containers do. The feature set of MS.DI is deliberately minimal to try to make it into a Least-Common Denominator.
As I mentioned in the comment, there is a workaround. The workaround involves iterating over the list of ServiceDescriptors and replacing any one of them that contains Custom.ILogger as dependency. The code below demonstrates this:
services.AddLogging();
services.AddSingleton(typeof(NewLoggerWrapper<>));

// This code must run after all registrations have been made.
for (int i = 0; i < services.Count; i++)
{
    ServiceDescriptor descriptor = services[i];

    // For simplicity, this example skips keyed registrations.
    if (descriptor.IsKeyedService) continue;
    // It's impossible to handle factory registrations.
    if (descriptor.ImplementationType is null) continue;
    
    var ctors = descriptor.ImplementationType.GetConstructors();

    // For simplicity, this example only handles types with a single public ctors
    if (ctors.Length != 1) continue;
    // Check if the constructor contains the custom ILogger
    var parameters = ctors[0].GetParameters();
    if (!parameters.Any(p => p.ParameterType == typeof(Custom.ILogger))) continue;

    Type logger = typeof(NewLoggerWrapper<>)
        .MakeGenericType(descriptor.ImplementationType);

    // Replace with a factory registration that injects NewLoggerWrapper<T>.
    services[i] = new ServiceDescriptor(
        serviceType: descriptor.ServiceType,
        lifetime: descriptor.Lifetime,
        factory: sp => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(
            provider: sp,
            instanceType: descriptor.ImplementationType,
            parameters: new[] { sp.GetRequiredService(logger) }));
}

Some of the shortcomings of this example are mentioned in the code. The downsides mentioned in the code, however, could be resolved with some effort. Unfortunately, the method above will not work on factory registrations  (e.g. .AddTransient<IService>(sp => MyService(sp.GetService<ILogger>())) and this limitation can't be fixed.
This limitation wouldn't be that bad if MS.DI was more feature rich. Unfortunately, because of the limited feature set, many more advanced features need to be implemented by making use of factory registrations. A library such as Scrutor, adds decorator support to MS.DI. But it uses the same method as the code above, i.e. it replaces ImplementationType registrations with factory registrations. (side note: Microsoft's AddHttpClient extension method takes a similar approach)
But that means that Scrutor's applied decorators won't be injected with your NewLoggerWrapper<T>.
But this is just one example of the many complications you'll run into when trying this technique.
